# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer'

Tags: node.js, typescript, cryptojs

I have implemented an encryption method in node which works correctly, but I'm  having trouble decrypting due to typeScript issues. This is my encryption method that works just fine and the example I'm following

[example](http:///https://gist.github.com/vlucas/2bd40f62d20c1d49237a109d491974eb)

```
private encryptWifiPassword = (param1: string, password: string) => {

        const ENCRYPTION_KEY = param1.padStart(32, '0'); // Must be 256 bits (32 characters)
        const IV_LENGTH = 16; // For AES, this is always 16

        const iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH);
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY), iv);
        let encrypted = cipher.update('prefix'+ password);
        encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);

        const pskEncripted = iv.toString('base64') + ':' + encrypted.toString('base64')
            return pskEncripted
};
```

This is my decryption method that won't work

```
  private decryptWifiPassword(param1: string, password: string): string {

        const ENCRYPTION_KEY = param1.padStart(32, '0')
        let textParts = password.split(':');
     
        let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(),'base64'); //this is the part with the issue
        
        let encryptedText = Buffer.from(textParts.join(':'), 'base64');
      
        let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY), iv);
       let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
      
       decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
       
       return decrypted.toString();
    
}
```

When I try to decrypt, the message I'm getting is this one:

```
No overload matches this call.

  Overload 1 of 5, '(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer, byteOffset?: number | undefined, length?: number | undefined): Buffer', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(obj: { valueOf(): string | object; } | { [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "string"): string; }, byteOffset?: number | undefined, length?: number | undefined): Buffer', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ valueOf(): string | object; } | { [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "string"): string; }'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ valueOf(): string | object; } | { [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "string"): string; }'.
  Overload 3 of 5, '(str: string, encoding?: "ascii" | "utf8" | "utf-8" | "utf16le" | "ucs2" | "ucs-2" | "base64" | "latin1" | "binary" | "hex" | undefined): Buffer', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I have tried to make this -->  let iv = Buffer.from(textParts[0],'base64'); but this is what i get as decipher

```
 Decipheriv {
  _decoder: null,
 _options: undefined,
  [Symbol(kHandle)]: {}
 }
```

Also I tried this  but it doesn't work either

```
let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(),'base64') as string
```

I'm new in crypto and any help would be great.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 7):

TypeScript is telling you that the return type of [`textParts.shift()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/387b6dc3e143c22deb8959eb0480462d32f31ef7/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1261-L1264) is possibly `undefined`. You need to either check in your function that the value is not `undefined` before calling `Buffer.from()`, or use a [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```js
let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift()!, 'base64');
```